# Is it possible to use <h:link> tag to link self in JSF?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

What is the proper value of `outcome` attribute of tag [`<h:link>`](https://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.2/vdldocs/facelets/h/link.html) to reference the current page (the page the tag `h:link` is written in)?

Following rules for return values of action methods i tried

- `outcome=""`
- `outcome="#{null}"`
- `outcome="#{''}"`

but all of them ends up with error message *This link is disabled because a navigation case could not be matched*.

I use JSF 2.2 and I want to use default navifation (i.e. my `faces-config.xml` file contains just the root tag).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `outcome` attribute should be completely omited:

```
<h:link value="self link" />
```

Comment: Then why use a link at all? What is the usecase? Just to instantiate a new view?